# Hello, I need to know how to start 10 notepad and then stop all 10 processes using cmdlets (powershell only)

Tags: powershell, process, powershell-cmdlet, start-process

Start-process notepad | stop-process

pretty much all I know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Start-Process just starts a process; it does not provide a way to reference that process after it has been started. Another way to do it would be:

```
# // Declare an array to hold Process IDs
$aProcessIDs = @()

# // Create a Wscript.Shell object to use for running processes
$oWshShell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell

# // Start 10 instances of notepad
for ($i=1;$i -le 10;$i++)
{
    # // Run notepad.exe
    $oProcess = $oWshShell.Exec('notepad.exe')

    # // Add the ProcessID of the running process to the array
    $aProcessIDs += $oProcess.ProcessID
}

# /// Wait 10 seconds
Start-Sleep -s 10

# // Terminate all processes
foreach ($iProcessID in $aProcessIDs)
{
    Stop-Process -Id $iProcessID
}
```